# API deployed and serving... Services not showing up - GAE

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Everything seems ok with the endpoints in the API backend but my web client does not display any services in `_ah/api/explorer` url. The API shows up in local server but not at deployment. In the logs it clearly shows

> > **API configuration update serving**

**app.yaml**

```
application: mk-dev
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

- url: /_ah/spi/.*
script: main.api

- url: /.*
script: main.app
secure: always
```

Deployment is as follows;

```
03:13 PM Compilation completed.

03:13 PM Starting deployment.

03:13 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.

03:13 PM Deployment successful.

03:14 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.

03:14 PM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.

03:14 PM Will check again in 1 seconds.

03:14 PM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.

03:14 PM Will check again in 2 seconds.

03:14 PM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.

03:14 PM Will check again in 4 seconds.

03:14 PM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.

03:14 PM Will check again in 8 seconds.

03:14 PM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.

03:14 PM Completed update of app: mk-dev, version: v1

03:14 PM Uploading index definitions.
```

## **UPDATE**

Just checked in dev tools console;

```
Failed to load resource: https://mk-dev.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis resourse the server responded with a status of 404 ()

cb=gapi.loaded_0:46 Uncaught Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 [<html>  <head>   <title>404 Not Found</title>  </head>  <body>   <h1>404 Not Found</h1>   The resource could not be found.<br /><br />     </body> </html>]
```

Comment: you need to enable the browser to load unsafe scripts. Click the security icon in address bar of your browser.

Comment: @AvinashRaj please check the update in the question. Just realized the resource is actually not loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was making sure I migrate traffic from version "1" to "v1" in the cloud console settings. Works fine now.